# Swift 3 Compiler Errors with JSON and Dictionaries within URLSession.shared.dataTask

Tags: ios, swift, nsdictionary, swift3

After previous issues with this particular app code as 'solved' with help, a new issue has arisen with this code:

```
var properties: [String] = []
var unsortedDetails: [String] = []
var contacts: [[String]] = []
var propertySorting: [(key: String, ind: String, link: Bool)] = []
var autolinks: [Bool] = []
```

and, in the viewDidLoad function:

```
let contactsRequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxOLElujQcy1-ZUer1KgEvK16gkTLUqYftApjNCM_IRTL3HSuDk/exec?id=" + ID + "&sheet=" + Industry.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "+", options: NSString.CompareOptions.literal, range: nil))!)

        let contactsTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: contactsRequest as URLRequest)
        {(data, response, error) in
            do {
                let jsonResult: Dictionary = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as! [String : Any]

                let results = jsonResult[self.Industry] as! [[String : Any]]

                for key in results[0].keys {
                    self.propertySorting.append(key: (key as? String)!, ind: results[0].value(forKey: key as! String) as! String, link: results[1].value(forKey: key as! String) as! String != "X")
                }
                self.propertySorting.sort(by: {Int($0.ind) < Int($1.ind)})

                for property in self.propertySorting {
                    self.properties.append(property.key)
                    self.autolinks.append(property.link)
                }

                for contact in results {
                    self.contacts.append([])
                    for key in self.properties {
                        self.contacts[self.contacts.count-1].append(contact.value(forKey: key) as! String)
                    }
                }

                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                    let listController = self.viewControllers[0] as! ListController

                    listController.properties = self.properties
                    listController.contacts = self.contacts
                    listController.autolinks = self.autolinks

                    listController.tableView.reloadData()
                })

            } catch {
                print("FATAL ERROR")
            }
        }

        contactsTask.resume()
```

The issues now encountered are:
`Extra argument 'ind' in call` when propertySorting.append(...) is called, and if this (previously working) `ind` section is deleted, the same error is returned for `link`

Comment: jsonResult instead of Result and you got all key

Comment: The cause is  results[0] you are now accessing is not type of NSDictionary.
Let define like this
`let result0: NSDictionary = results[0];`
Syntax maybe not correct, please change it approriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `NSArray` and `NSDictionary` used Swift native `Array` and `Dictionary` and use `keys` with `Dictionary` to get array of all keys.

```
let jsonResult: Dictionary = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as! [String : Any]
let results = jsonResult[self.Industry] as! [[String : Any]]

for key in results[0].keys {

}
```

**Note:** There is no need to use `.mutableContainers` option with Swift native type object.

Comment: This definitely cleans up the look of the code, and makes more sense - however it introduces two new issues (whilst seemingly removing the others):
The first issue introduced is that it claims I've entered an extra value in this line: `self.propertySorting.append(key: (key as? String)!, ind: results[0].value(forKey: key as! String) as! String, link: results[1].value(forKey: key as! String) as! String != "X")`
Despite: `var propertySorting: [(key: String, ind: String, link: Bool)] = []` (and it worked fine before)
It also then claims that `contact` has no value `value`

Comment: Sorry, by 'extra value' I mean it claims there is no value `ind` in `propertySorting`, and if I delete that part (despite it being correct) in that line, it then claims the same thing for `link`

Comment: @OscarCooke-Abbott For that you need to show me the type of `propertySorting` and also show this custom method append

Comment: More specifically for the `contact` has no value `value`, it says `Value of type 'Dictionary<String, Any>' has no member 'value'

Comment: You need to edit your question with this new code and error.

Comment: I don't know what to change it to due to the entirely different nature of the two new errors and the unidentifiable source of error?

Comment: Changed the question

Comment: Ok, so after researching Swift-native Dictionaries, I found a way to fix the `value(...)` issue, and after some experimentation, I found that i can add values to the propertySorting array via creating the new Element separately first (something I was hoping to avoid, but it works anyway)

Comment: Sorry for late response, out from SO, happy to hear that you have solved that second issue,